# Calculating length of sub strings of consecutive characters MIPS

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, mips

I am writing a program using MIPs that takes an input string from the user and outputs the longest substring of consecutive identical characters. My problem seems to be that 'end' seems to be reached before the program outputs the target string. Any help is appreciated!

```
main:
    la $a0,input_msg        # Prompting input from user
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    li $v0, 8               # Reading string and storing in memory 
    la $a0, input_string
    li $a1, 100
    syscall


    li $t0, 0 
    la $t1, input_string            # address of the first element
    lb $a0, ($t1)               # input_string[0] (the first character)

    move $s0, $a0           # current_char=read_char();
    move $s1, $a0           # previous_char = input_string[0];
    move $s2, $a0           # final_char=input_string[0];

    li $s3, 1           # current_num_chars=1;
    li $s4, 1           # final_num_chars=1;


    la $t5, new_line

loop:

    addi $t0, $t0, 1        # for(k=1; k<i-1; k++)  {
    add $t1, $t1, $t0       
    lb $t3, ($t1)
    beq $s5, $t3, print_final
    move $s0, $t3           # current_char=input_string[k];

    bne $s0, $s1, else          # if(current_char == previous_char)
    addi $s3, $s3, 1        # current_num_chars++; 

    bge $s3, $s4, increase_final    # if(current_num_chars >= final_num_chars) {    

    move $s1, $s0
    j loop              # else do nothing

increase_final: 

    move $s2, $s0           # final_char=current_char;
    move $s4, $s3           # final_num_chars=current_num_chars; 

    move $s1, $s0
    j loop              # }


else:   
    move $s1, $s0   
    j loop              # else {
                    #   current_num_chars=1;
                    # }
                    # }

print_final:

    la $a0, output_msg
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $t2, 0

print_chars:    

    li $t2, 0           #  for(k=0; k<final_num_chars; k++)  {
    beq $t2, $s3, end

    move $a0, $s2           # print_char(final_char);
    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    j print_chars           # }

end:

    li   $v0, 4           # print_string("\n");
    la   $a0, new_line
    syscall

    li   $v0, 10          # exit()
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print_chars` loop compares `$t2` (which you just set to 0) to `$s3` to decide whether or not to jump to end.  Thus, it will always make the same comparison, and your loop will either exit the first time it is encountered, or never end.

Plus, the comment suggests that you should be comparing to `$s4`, not `$s3`.

Comment: Ah of course! I hadn't even noticed that! Thanks! Unfortunately now it runs but throws an error regarding ln58, which is the section beginning `loop:
 addi $t0, $t0, 1  # for(k=1; k<i-1; k++)  {
 add $t1, $t1, $t0  
    lb $t3, ($t1)
    beq $s3, $t5, print_chars   
 move $s0, $t3  # current_char=input_string[k];`

Comment: The original code is changed and should read
`la $s5, new_line` rather than `la $s4, new_line`
and the `bge $t0, $t8, end` is replaced by `beq $s3, $s5, print_chars`

Comment: Unless you can edit the question w/ the new code & issue, please close this question out & post a new one.